# performance tuning Timescape to get active instruments

Tags: query-performance

I have a QL+ query in [timescape](http://www.xenomorph.com/timescape-edm/)

`DatabaseItems(database := 'Silver', Category := 'Bonds').Where(not(iserror(|isactive|)))`  (3 min)

The schema I'm using has a boolean field on BondItems called `IsActive`.
I would expect this query to return in similar order to the query

`DatabaseItems('Silver','Bonds')` (6 sec).

What is the better way to write this query so that I can get realistic performance?

*[timescape]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The underlying data service for Timescape is not a relational
   database. The underlying data service is object based and highly
   optimised for timeseries analysis.
2. Timescape does not support adding
   custom indexes.

While custom indexes can't be added to the data structure, one can create index objects, with references. In this way one might create a category of `indexes`, within the `indexes` category, one would create an object say ActiveBonds, with a timeseries of lists of bonds. As bonds are added or removed from the active list, a new row in the timeseries is created with a new list of bonds. The list of bonds needs to be a list of `Reference Items`, not names, so that you can access the references directly and query on them directly as objects, rather than having to do further looks.

The query you'd like to construct is then

```
DatabaseItem('silver','Acivebonds')
.|itemlist|.Data(0)
.Values(|mid price|('bbg_data').LastValue)
```

*[Timescape]*